# Function name as string

Tags: python, string, function

I got three functions, named Aufgabe[1,2,3]. I want to make it so that if someone enters in the console "1" `Aufgabe1` gets triggered and so on. Is it possible to do?

```
AufgabenNummer = int(input("Welche Aufgabe willst du öffnen?\n"))
    Aufgabe = "Aufgabe" + str(AufgabenNummer)
    Aufgabe()

def Aufgabe1():
    zahl1 = int(input("Erste Zahl...?\n"))
    zahl2 = int(input("Zweite Zahl...?\n"))
    print (str(zahl1) + "+" + str(zahl2) + "=" + str(zahl1+zahl2))

def Aufgabe2():
    for i in range(0,11):
        print(i)

def Aufgabe3():
    name = int(input("Hallo wie heißt du?\n"))
    print ("Hallo" + str(name))
```

Comment: why are you calling int on a variable called name and then casting to str?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is to maintain a dictionary of name/function pairs:

```
function_table = {
   'Aufgabe3' : Aufgabe3,
   'Aufgabe2' : Aufgabe2,
   'Aufgabe1' : Aufgabe1,
}
```

Then call the appropriate function by looking it up in the table

```
function_table['Aufgabe1']()
```

This allows you finer control over the mapping of inputs to functions allowing you to refactor freely without changing your program interface.

Comment: im new to Python can you tell me how i intigrate it into my script?

Comment: Where you call `Aufgabe()` in line 3, you should instead call `function_table[Aufgabe]()`

Comment: AufgabenNummer = int(input("Welche Aufgabe willst du öffnen?\n"))
Aufgabe = "Aufgabe" + str(AufgabenNummer)
function_table['Aufgabe1']()

def Aufgabe1():
    zahl1 = int(input("Erste Zahl...?\n"))
    zahl2 = int(input("Zweite Zahl...?\n"))
    print (str(zahl1) + "+" + str(zahl2) + "=" + str(zahl1+zahl2))

def Aufgabe2():
    for i in range(0,11):
        print(i)

def Aufgabe3():
    name = int(input("Hallo wie heißt du?\n"))
    print ("Hallo" + str(name))

Comment: Welche Aufgabe willst du öffnen?
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\Desktop\Selber Programmiert\Python\Aufgaben.py", line 3, in <module>
    function_table['Aufgabe1']()
NameError: name 'function_table' is not defined